# How can I find the telegram api link?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, telegram

I want to create a **telegram client** in c# but i can’t find the api link. 
The bot api has no use for me!
It would be really great if somebody could help me and tell me, where i can find it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to where to find the API information for the Telegram Messaging Platform? It's not quite clear from your question, but if so, here's the link to that API: https://core.telegram.org/api

If this is what you're looking for, I was able to find it by googling "Telegram API" - which should be your first instinct. If not, then your question is not clear enough and doesn't provide enough detail of what you're looking to get help with.

Comment: i want to make a telegram client and i need the link, where i should send the api request to.

Thank you for answearing so soon!

Comment: Sonja, check the link I provided and look on the website for more info.

Comment: unfortunately i still don't find it. but thank you very much for your help!